# Generate Email Newsletter HTML from Posts published within a Date Range?

Tags: plugins, newsletter, html-email

I would like to basically send a newsletter type email to a listy I have using a 3rd party such as MailChimp.  My goal though is to be able to find or build a WordPress plugin that will allow me to get all the new Posts that are within 2 date ranges...It will then allow me to generate the HTML for Posts within that date range and then I can export the html generate to my 3rd part newsletter service (MailChimp, AWeber, etc...)

So If I want to send a monthly email to my list which will show all the post for the month or a bi-weekly newsletter with all posts made in that period, it will allow me to simply set the date ranges and show all posts, thumbnail images, title, links, description....I can then maybe drag and drop to arrange them if needed and evenm delete any that I might not want to show up in this "months" newsletter.

The plugin/wordpress functionality will not need to do anything involving an email list, simply generate the html for my emails which will be sent from elsewhere!

I would imagine such a plugin would have to exist but have yet to find one.

I am thinking I might have to build it myself but I wanted to ask for any imput on here first to my fellow WordPress Developers to see if anyone knows of such a plugin or functionality?

Would appreciate any feedback on this project, if you know of a similar plugin?  If not, perhaps you can give some ideas for desired functionality of features if I have to end up building my own plugin from scratch for this?

Some feature ideas:

- Drag and drop to arrange order of posts in he generated Newsletter HTML
- Delete button on each post in the generated newsletter HTML which removes that post from the DOM and generated HTML
- Option to select which Post Types it will fetch
- If multiple Post Types, then option to have them listed in separate Sections or to have them all combined and sorted only by published date.  For example a Post post type and a Project post type.  Combined it would list a blog post then 2 projects and then another 3 blog posts and then another project if there date order allowed that.  IF separated then all Blog posts would be in 1 grid block and the Projects would be below that block in there own section.
- Newsletter Post Type which will allow you to generate the Newsletter HTML but then also save it as a post record on your WordPress site to act as an online Archived version.

So does anything similar to this featureset exist already?  If not, any ideas for moew features if I have to build it myself?  If the later, is there any interest in such a plugin, likely open source?

I am asking this question on WOrdPress StackExchange because I have wanted such a plugin for a long time now and I feel my best chance of a fellow WordPress Developer knowing of such a featured plugin will be on this site!  If nothing exists then you guys are also the best group of people to get feedback on features one should have if it needs to be built from scratch!  I appreciate any info and help on this journey, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think [MailPoet](http://www.mailpoet.com) gets pretty close, you can setup a template, drag and drop posts, etc. You can even have it send via Mandrill or Railgun, etc if you want.

Otherwise it doesn't seem like it would be that hard to to setup the generated HTML. It's really the "choosing posts" that's the hard part since there's a ton of ways to go about it.

You could spit out a custom template and whatever posts you want based on date but I'm guessing you want more flexibility. If I was creating this for a client, I'd probably use something like [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) with a settings page where you'd pick which posts—maybe with a repeater field—and then spit out the generated HTML somewhere based on those settings.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a plugin that does this. In search of one myself. Closest I have found is [MailOptin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173011/generate-email-newsletter-html-from-posts-published-within-a-date-range) which can send a daily, weekly or monthly email digest of published posts.